# Multi-Table Django Join

Tags: mysql, django, join

Relatively new to Django. I'm building a light CRM in Django. The MYSQL database I built uses associative entities to help deal with many-to-many relationships.

I'm trying to use the associative entity "contactdeal" to connect "deals" with "contacts".

See models and views below.

`Models`:

```
class Account1(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)       
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)    
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)       
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)      
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)    
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)      
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    biztype = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'account'

class Contact1(models.Model):
    contact_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(Account1, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='account_id', blank=False, null=False)
    contact_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    
class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contact'

class Contactdeal(models.Model):
    contactdeal_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contactdeal_deal_fk = models.ForeignKey('Deal', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='contactdeal_deal_fk', blank=True, null=True)
    contactdeal_contact_fk = models.ForeignKey(Contact1, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='contactdeal_contact_fk', db_column='contactdeal_contact_fk', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contactdeal'

class Deal(models.Model):
    deal_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    deal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    est_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    deal_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'deal'
```

`View`:

```
def deal(request):
    deal = Contactdeal.objects.select_related('contactdeal_contact_fk', 'contactdeal_deal_fk')
    template = loader.get_template('deal.html')
    context = {
        'deal' : deal,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

`Template`:

```
{% for x in deal %}
<tbody>
<tr class="table-active">
    <td>{{x.contactdeal_deal_fk.deal_name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.contactdeal_deal_fk.est_value}}</td>
    <td>{{x.contactdeal_contact_fk.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.contactdeal_contact_fk.account_id}}</td>
    <td><a href="updateaccount/{{ x.id }}">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="deleteaccount/{{x.id}}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

for the most part, I've been successful using the select_related approach to join both contacts and deals using the associative entity contactdeal.

Where this falls short, however, is when I want to show the "account" each "contact" belongs to. I can show "account_id" which is the FK that links the "contact" table and "account" table, but I can't seem to come up with a way to add another join that will allow me to use the "account_id" FK in the contact table to pull the name associated with that "account_id" in the "account" table.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I am going to try to create a view in MYSQL that achieves the connection I am looking to establish and turn that into its own model, not managed using Django.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).